# Is there any way by which we can create custom ace editor autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Ace editor only shows suggestion and a metadata. There are couple of more things that I want to show, for example some icons related to different suggestions etc.

I want to change the style and markup of autocmplete to support more meta data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ACE Editor Autocomplete - custom strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041816/ace-editor-autocomplete-custom-strings)

Comment: I don't want custom strings. What I want is to style or change the markup of default autocomplete

Comment: depends on what exactly you want to change, cloud9 does something like that in https://github.com/c9/c9.ide.language.core/blob/bfb5dd2acc72b4d3023d0f46322e67f97d77e33f/completedp.js#L108-L109