# Ace Editor difference between addCompleter and setCompleters

Tags: reactjs, ace-editor, react-ace

I am using the ***react-ace*** editor and using the sql language mode and trying to include the table and column name as part of the auto completion. I found this https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/How-to-enable-Autocomplete-in-the-Ace-editor which uses ***addCompleter*** and some answers here uses ***setCompleters***  [ACE Editor Autocomplete - custom strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041816/ace-editor-autocomplete-custom-strings) for adding autocompletion. What is the difference between these two and which one we need to use if we need to add the table names and column names as part of SQL autocomplete