# How to make ace python editor correctly identify class variables as local variables?

Tags: javascript, editor, ace-editor

[image]

As shown above, when I type a variable name, if the prompted variable name is in a class, the variable will be prompted as a local variable, is there any way to remove such a prompt, that is, the variable in the class will not be prompted in any way locally?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a "local variable", but an "identifier local to this file" (as supposed to a built-in or a keyword).

You can write your own auto-completers to be more context-aware. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30047705/5578773) a small sample - you're given a code location and return an array of completions.

Comment: I know how to write a simple completer, but how does this function work, and how do I go about classifying the variables and local variables in the category? Do I need to involve traversal of the abstract syntax tree here?

Comment: You would need _some_ sort of structure representation - it can be a complete AST (there are a few libraries and even Python implementations in JS) or a simpler algorithm making a few assumptions about code structure (like class fields and methods being inside the class rather than assigned in some function that the constructor calls).